# IBM-ODM 8.10 Build Automation Tool - Error Deploying To RES

Tags: java, windows, ibm-odm

I am trying to automate the build/deployment process in IBM ODM v8.10 using the Build Automation Tool documented here:
[Rule Designer build automation tool](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSQP76_8.10.x/com.ibm.odm.dserver.rules.designer.run/build_topics/tpc_buildautotool.html)

I am trying to deploy a Decision Service to an RES instance hosted on a Linux server. I get the below error which is not indicitive of what is causing the array index OB error. Has anyone who has used this tool encountered this issue? I am running this on a Windows machine.

`[java] 2019-12-31 13:45:32.744 [INFO] Generating the RuleApp.
 [java] 2019-12-31 13:45:34.821 [INFO] RuleApp Build Status
 [java] 2019-12-31 13:45:34.822 [INFO] RuleApp file written to: C:\Program Files\IBM\ODM810\studio\samples\brmanagement\buildautomationtool\project\attachmentfilter-rules\output\ServerDeployment.jar
 [java] 2019-12-31 13:45:34.823 [INFO] RuleApp build finished with no errors.
 [java] 2019-12-31 13:45:34.824 [INFO] Deploying the RuleApp to SampleServer (http://odmdv:9080/res).
 [java] 2019-12-31 13:45:34.901 [INFO] RuleApp Deployment
 [java] 2019-12-31 13:45:34.903 [SEVERE] An error prevented the RuleApp to be deployed to SampleServer (http://odmdv:9080/res): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 13
 [java]  ilog.rules.crypto.IlrEncryptionServiceException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 13
 [java]     at ilog.rules.crypto.IlrEncryptionUtility.decrypt(IlrEncryptionUtility.java:193)
 [java]     at ilog.rules.crypto.IlrEncryptionService.decrypt(IlrEncryptionService.java:43)
 [java]     at com.ibm.rules.decisionservice.internal.RESTAPIClientFactory4.createDsResWebClient(RESTAPIClientFactory4.java:96)
 [java]     at com.ibm.rules.decisionservice.internal.RESTAPIClientFactory4.createClient(RESTAPIClientFactory4.java:79)
 [java]     at com.ibm.rules.decisionservice.internal.RESTAPIClientFactory4.createClient(RESTAPIClientFactory4.java:27)
 [java]     at com.ibm.rules.decisionservice.internal.RESClient$2.execute(RESClient.java:309)
 [java]     at com.ibm.rules.decisionservice.internal.RESClient$2.execute(RESClient.java:303)
 [java]     at com.ibm.rules.decisionservice.internal.RESClient.safeInvokeRES(RESClient.java:136)
 [java]     at com.ibm.rules.decisionservice.internal.RESClient.deploy(RESClient.java:303)
 [java]     at com.ibm.rules.decisionservice.internal.RESRESTClient4.deploy(RESRESTClient4.java:100)
 [java]     at com.ibm.rules.studio.model.decisionservice.impl.Server.deploy(Server.java:320)
 [java]     at com.ibm.rules.decisionservice.DsRuleAppDeployManager.deploy(DsRuleAppDeployManager.java:43)
 [java]     at com.ibm.rules.decisionservice.DsDeployManager.deploy(DsDeployManager.java:81)
 [java]     at com.ibm.rules.studio.decisionservice.SDsXOMDeploymentJob.deploy(SDsXOMDeploymentJob.java:247)
 [java]     at com.ibm.rules.studio.decisionservice.SDsRuleAppDeploymentJob.deployRuleApp(SDsRuleAppDeploymentJob.java:136)
 [java]     at com.ibm.rules.studio.decisionservice.SDsRuleAppDeploymentJob.deploy(SDsRuleAppDeploymentJob.java:66)
 [java]     at com.ibm.rules.studio.decisionservice.SDsXOMDeploymentJob.runInWorkspace(SDsXOMDeploymentJob.java:103)
 [java]     at com.ibm.rules.studio.decisionservice.headless.SDsHeadlessDeployer.run(SDsHeadlessDeployer.java:355)
 [java]     at com.ibm.rules.studio.decisionservice.headless.SDsHeadlessDeployer.start(SDsHeadlessDeployer.java:149)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
 [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 [java]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 [java]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1472)
 [java]     at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:34)
 [java] Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 13
 [java]     at ilog.rules.util.IlrBase64DecoderStream.decode(IlrBase64DecoderStream.java:151)
 [java]     at ilog.rules.crypto.IlrEncryptionUtility.decrypt(IlrEncryptionUtility.java:189)
 [java]     ... 32 more
 [java] 2019-12-31 13:45:34.905 [INFO]
 [java] 2019-12-31 13:45:34.908 [INFO] Refreshing '/attachmentfilter-rules/output'.
 [java] 2019-12-31 13:45:34.926 [INFO] Workspace auto-building is enabled.
 [java] 2019-12-31 13:45:34.930 [INFO] Saving workspace.`

Comment: I am wondering why anything is being written to the ODM install folders during build/deployment?    For example: "RuleApp file written to: C:\Program Files\IBM\ODM810\studio\samples\brmanagement\buildautomationtool\project\attachmentfilter-rules\output\ServerDeployment.jar"

Comment: The default port for RES is 9090, while the trace you provided shows 9080. Are you sure 9080 is correct?

Comment: Its just a POC, Im just trying to get the RuleApp built. As for the port I believe we use 9080 in Rule Designer to deploy via RuleApp project.